# Traefik ingress controller on minikube: External IP pending

Tags: kubernetes, traefik, minikube, traefik-ingress

I am trying to deploy a Traefik Ingress controller in my minikube environment by following [this](https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/how-to-configure-traefik-for-routing-applications-in-kubernetes_594720):

```
helm install stable/traefik --name-template traefik --set dashboard.enabled=true,dashboard.domain=dashboard.traefik,rbac.enabled=true --namespace kube-system
```

Even after half an hour I still see that External IP is pending:

```
pascals@pascals:~$ kubectl get svc -l app=traefik -n kube-system 
NAME                TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
traefik             LoadBalancer   10.96.172.128   <pending>     443:30812/TCP,80:31078/TCP   20m
traefik-dashboard   ClusterIP      10.96.56.105    <none>        80/TCP                       20m
```

Ideally I would like to reach `http://dashboard.traefik` but I am not able to do so.

I tried to assign an External Ip using the `kubectl patch` Api:

```
kubectl patch svc traefik -n kube-system -p '{"spec":{"externalIPs":["192.168.99.107"]}}'
```

where, 192.168.99.107 is the minikube ip. This however still did not solve my problem.

Appreciate any nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 3):

The external IP is assigned by the ServiceController if any `cloud provider` used in the cluster, usually in managed clusters.

In a `minikube` cluster, LoadBalance-typed Service will never have an external IP. You can access Services through `minikubeip:nodeport`, or running `minikube service`. For the Service `traefik-dashboard`, it should be a NodePort-typed Service first.

Answer (score 1):

You should install some Kubernetes bare-metal load balancer, like [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf)